# How do I add to beginning using text file using a .bat instead of append to end?

Tags: batch-file

I have a **batch** file that returns a list of data. Currently, every time I run the **script**, it appends the newly pulled data to the end of the text file. Is there a way that I can add the new data to the beginning of the file, rather than append it to the end? I need to it work this way because the data is pulled *chronologically*, and I'd like the text file to be sorted from most recent to oldest.

```
@ECHO OFF
```

REM Used to log server users stats into a text file located in the local c:\userlog directory

```
ECHO Terminal Server Users, %Date%, %TIME%>>c:\Userlogs\UserListTest.txt
quser /server:servername>>C:\Userlogs\UserListTest.txt

START C:\Userlogs\UserListTest.txt
Exit
```

any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8):

Following will work as you want

```
    echo this will come at the begining of file >>log.txt
    type log1.txt >> log.txt
    del log1.txt
    ren log.txt log1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

one way using temporary file.

prepend.bat :

```
:: copy existing file to a temporary file
copy c:\temp\existing.txt c:\temp\temp.txt
:: replace content with your new value
echo test >c:\temp\existing.txt
::  append content of temp file
for /F %%i in (c:\temp\temp.txt) do echo %%i >> c:\temp\existing.txt
:: remove tempfile
del c:\temp\temp.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try using the code below.

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Store the string  you want to prepend in a variable
SET "text=%1"
:: copy the contents into a temp file
type userlist.txt > temp.txt
:: Now Overwrite the file with the contents in "text" variable
echo %text% > userlist.txt 
:: Now Append the Old Contents
type temp.txt >> userlist.txt
:: Delete the temporary file
del temp.txt
```

Hope this solves your problem. :)

Answer (score -1):

One of the big issues in Batch is building ordered arrays, which has to be done via files, Batch doesn't have an array construct in it.  One option you can do to force things into memory and save some IOPS in batch is use a ramdisk, making sure to abstract the filepaths into variables.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the options you mention, or maybe give a few examples ?

Answer (score -2):

First, read the contents of the file. Append that to what you want to add to the beginning and write all of that to the file.