# Entries in host file at particular line

Tags: windows-7, host

I am looking for a script that can add host entries in a windows 7 host files at **particular lines** or **just after the default text** in host file.

I came across this thread in your forum [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881762/how-to-edit-hosts-using-batch-filecheck-for-line-add-if-doesnt-exist-delete-if/37484144#37484144) that can add/remove the lines perfectly but it adds the lines at the end of the file not at the top. can you please help with the same?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/14597270/2113612

Answer (score 0):

hey thanks for the link. 
Since i have limited exposure to batch files, I wanted to check that method offline first

1) created a txt file **dns.txt** with some DNS entries

```
1.2.3.4 abcd.com
2.3.4.5 bcde.com
3.4.5.6 cdef.com
4.5.6.7 defg.com
```

2) created a batch file with one line code in it:

```
for /F %%i in (c:\temp\dns.txt) do echo %%i >> "D:\hosts"
```

3) but when i check the host file, it only has IP entries and not the hostnames against it.

```
 ==================
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself. 
#   127.0.0.1 localhost 
#   ::1 localhost 

1.2.3.4
2.3.4.5
3.4.5.6
4.5.6.7 
====================
```

what is wrong !!?